# How to use ‘not equal to’ inequality constraint in fmincon?

Tags: matlab, constraints, mathematical-optimization, minimization

How can I set the constraints for the solution (`x1`,`x2`), so that `x1 ~= x2` (`x1` is not `x2`) in the MATLAB function `fmincon`?
In numerical sense: `x1` should not get close to `x2`.

Comment: How are you using fmincon? You might need to add more script to get a correct answer. Did you try an if statement to flag when x1 was approaching x2?

Comment: I'm new to fmincon. 
So i tried it with just an function handle and lower-/upper bounds to constrain this function. I'm getting some singularity problems when two parameters of the same value will be used.

`[x1, x2] = fmincon(Fcn, [initPara1, initPara2], [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options);`

How can i flag this while in this function? Is it possible to reach it with the 9th input (nonlcon) with another function handle?

Comment: so where are you getting x1 and x2?

Comment: Sorry, this should be more accurate. X1 and X2 are my solutions to fmincon.

Comment: If you call it that way, you're only getting one solution, and your fval. "[x,fval] = fmincon(___), for any syntax, returns the value of the objective function fun at the solution x."

Comment: Ok,

that was fast... I have the solution:

`fmincon(Fcn, initPara, [-1,1], [-1.0E-7], [], [], lb, ub, [], options)`

Sorry for you time! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really can't. This constraint introduces a non-convexity that `Fmincon` is not designed to handle. The proper formulation could lead to an MINLP problem that requires an MINLP solver. If there are only 2 variables involved you can solve two different problems, one with `x1 <= x2 - 0.001` and the other with `x1 >= x2 + 0.001` and pick the best solution.

Comment: @Erwin  Btw do you know any other function that's designed to handle that?

Comment: @SardarUsama There are MINLP solvers with Matlab interfaces. To my knowledge, standard Matlab toolboxes do not contain MINLP solvers (I am discounting meta-heuristics here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To express the constraint `x1 ≠ x2` in the form of `A*x ≤ b`, it would be either of these:

```
  x(1) – x(2) ≤ –eps    % x(2) ≥ x(1) + eps   
– x(1) + x(2) ≤ –eps    % x(1) ≥ x(2) + eps
```

As per the first one, `x(2)` should be greater than `x(1)`. And as per the second one, `x(1)` should be greater than `x(2)`. The combination of above would be:

```
A = [1, -1; -1,  1];  
b = [-eps; -eps];
```

But you cannot use this `A` and `b` directly because it would imply that `x(1) + x(2) = eps` which is not correct. So to find the minimum value of the function and the value of `x` for which it is minimum, consider both the conditions separately, i.e. one at a time, and see which minimises more. i.e.

```
[x(1,:), fval(1)] = fmincon(Fcn, x0, A(1,:), b(1), [], [], lb, ub, [], options);
[x(2,:), fval(2)] = fmincon(Fcn, x0, A(2,:), b(2), [], [], lb, ub, [], options);
[Minfval, tmpInd] = min(fval);   %Finding the minimum value of these
Req_x = x(tmpInd,:);             %Required solution
```